# What is equivalent formulas?

Tags: logic, algorithms

What does it mean if two logical formulas are equivalent, for instance F1 and F2? When both are tautologies or contradictions does that means they are equivalent? What if they are neither that?

Comment: It gets kind of tricky. Formally, it is if we can prove  $\phi\leftrightarrow \psi$. A consequence is that all theorems are equivalent. However, the term is often used informally to mean that $\phi\leftrightarrow\psi$ is not terribly difficult to prove.

Comment: @AndréNicolas They only come as equivalent within a logical formal system under some rule of inference.  With a different rule of inference or different axioms, they are by no means necessarily interderivable.

Comment: You are certainly right, I should have mentioned a formal theory $T$. As to the logic, naturally one assumes correct reasoning. In particular, the standard axioms and rules of inference of first-order logic are correct. Some people are interested in weakening them. Kind of like seeing how well one can run with feet tied together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume we are working in propositional logic since you are talking about tautologies. Then to say that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are equivalent is to say that for every valuation of the atoms in $\varphi$ and/or $\psi$, the two wffs take the same truth-values. Or equivalently (why?) the wff $\varphi \leftrightarrow \psi$ is a tautology (where that's the material biconditional).

It follows from this definition if $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are both tautologies then they are equivalent (why?). Similarly if they are both contradictions. But wffs can be equivalent even if neither is a tautology or a contradiction. For example, $P \land Q$ and $\neg(\neg P \lor \neg Q)$ are equivalent.

The notion of equivalence can be applied more generally e.g. in first-order logic. Then to say that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are equivalent is to say that for every interpretation of the non-logical vocabulary in $\varphi$ and/or $\psi$ and every assignment of values to free variables, the wffs take the same truth-value. Etc.